# Safe to use a 19V 2.15A DC adapter (a laptop charger) for an accessory that uses a 25V 0.75A DC adapter?

Tags: usb, power-supply, power, voltage

I picked up a USB steering wheel at a thrift store and it requires a power supply to 'nudge' the wheel back into place (if you let go of it, for example). It requires 25 Volts, 0.75A, yet the closest thing I can find is an old laptop charger which is 19 Volts, 2.15A.

Normally I wouldn't be comfortable using a device with a disparity in voltage, but since it's only a steering wheel with a built in motor, I was wondering if it would be alright. I don't need perfect performance, I just don't want to damage anything.

Comment: It is always quite beneficial to mention model names/numbers in your question if you want a better answer. There are many teardowns of steering wheels, where the size and type of driving motors are exposed, so people can make a better guess about effects of undervoltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't reverse polarity, it should not be any risk of damage.
As the supply has a lower voltage, it might not work properly, but at least it shouldn't damage it.

Comment: Not true.  Too low power may cause heating.  This is true of motors and solid state circuitry.

Comment: Blackbeagle is right.  Depending on the type of motor, voltage this much lower may not be enough to operate the motor, or to spin it at the intended speed.  In that case, much of the power could be converted into heat and damage it.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok.
When your device need 25VDC and 0.75A, you must make sure that the power supply is around 25VDC and **capable** to supply at least 0.75A.

But the problem is, is 19VDC strong enough to drive your device? If yes. Nothing problem.
Don't worry about amperage, Input current is same as output current. So, your device only draws 0.75 from your, says, 100A power supply.

And as cristhofer weber says, as long as polarity is not reversed, it is safe.

Answer (score -2):

Do not use it.

Old - 25v * .75A = 18.75W

New - 19V * 2.15A = 40.85W - thats more than twice the power

If you plug in the new charger, you could fry the steering wheel

Comment: The total amount of wattage a power supply can deliver should be of little concern. It won't 'force feed' the appliance with 40W, the appliance will draw as much power as needed.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber you are making an assumption that it will regulate the power.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Keltari, having a large amperage shouldn't be a problem, as the device will draw only what it needs. I do think low amperage is a problem though, as the device might try and draw more than the adapter can handle and damage it.

Comment: @wptreanor does not change the fact the adapter shouldn't be used

Comment: @Keltari Not really. As long as the maximum amps supplied are more than the appliance need. A regulator regulates the voltage.

Comment: @Keltari, seriously?  All of the previous questions about adapters with higher available amperage and you post this?

Comment: What a nonsense. Please remove this answer. -1. There is absolutely no reason not to try the 19V supply. The backforce may be not as strong as it should be, but there is no risk.